# Unable to call curl function from observer page

Tags: magento-1.9

After check out, I need to pass order details to another page. So i created new module called Order_Add.Module triggering but not passing the values;
Below i am providing my config.xml and observer.php file

Config.xml : 
[image]

Observer.php

[image]

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What are you missing here is the HTTPHEADER:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));`

Add this line after`CURLOPT_VERBOSE` in your method.